# Save File Through Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way that I can save image through excel?

I want something like button or anything (in excel) that allow user to load a image and then save it into a specific file. I also need the image to be rename same as the reject id for each row.

The image does not need to be shown on the excel. I need this because my co-worker is not good with computing and always lose track of the reject image.

[image: Excel data sheet]

[image: File]

Comment: Please tell me if this thing is impossible to do. So that i can work on other method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is possible. Just do it manually while you record it in a macro. If you still have problems, show us what you tried, we might have a look.

Answer (score 0):

example: in sheet 2 resize all cells to have a width of 27 and height of 150 or whatever size you are comfortable, list is in sheet 1

```
Sub Insert_Picture()
Dim myPicture As Variant
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim PlaceAtCell As Range
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = 1
i = 1
myPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    ("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png),*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif *.png", , "SELECT FILE(S) TO IMPORT", MultiSelect:=True)
If VarType(myPicture) = vbBoolean Then
    MsgBox "NO FILES SELECTED"
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsArray(myPicture) Then
    For lLoop = LBound(myPicture) To UBound(myPicture)
        
             Set PlaceAtCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, 1)
        
             With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
                 filename:=myPicture(lLoop), _
                 LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                 SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                 Left:=PlaceAtCell.Left, _
                 Width:=PlaceAtCell.Width, _
                 Top:=PlaceAtCell.Top, _
                 Height:=PlaceAtCell.Height)
                 .Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
                 .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            End With
            i = i + 1
            lRow = lRow + 1
    Next lLoop
End If

MsgBox "Picture(s) inserted!"

End Sub
```